# Spring cloud stream sqs binder function binding not working

Tags: java, spring, amazon-sqs, spring-cloud-stream

I have set up a spring cloud stream with sqs binder https://github.com/idealo/spring-cloud-stream-binder-sqs where there are two applications producer and consumer. Here my configuration

**1) Producer Application**

**application.yml**

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      bindings:
        sourceForBroker-out-0:
          destination: testqueue
      function:
        definition: sourceForBroker
```

**Spring function**

```
@Bean
public Supplier<Flux<Model>> sourceForBroker() {
    // push data in queue logic
}
```

**2) Consumer Application**

**application.yml**

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      bindings:
        req1:
          destination: testqueue
      function:
        bindings:
          consumer1-in-0: req1
        definition: consumer1
```

**Spring function**

```
@Bean
public Consumer<Model> consumer1() {
    return t-> System.out.println("id:" + t.getId());
}
```

I have checked logs for producer application able push data in the queue as well as I have also check consumer logs and found that consumer application received messages that sent by producer application to testqueue but my function i.e consumer1(..) not getting those data.

Comment: Just an FYI, spring-cloud-stream team and spring in general is not the maintainer of SQS Binder, so perhaps there is some additional tag you can use to expend the reach of your post?